# Diode emission coefficient and saturation current

Tags: diodes, simulation, ltspice, reverse-breakdown

I have created a Zener diode model in LTSpice, and now I am trying to simulate it with different values of the saturation current (IS), emission coefficient (N) and breakdown voltage (BV) using Spice.
These terms are not entirely clear to me, so analyzing the results of my simulations would be problematic. This is my understanding of the above in layman's terms:

Saturation current - This is the maximum reverse current caused by the combination of the minority particles in the p and n junctions, beyond which the zener diode enters breakdown voltage and this current exceeds rapidly, likely to damage the diode.

Emission coefficient - This concept is not clear to me. From what I read online, it is a value between 1 and 2. Closer to 1 means greater forward bias. But how do I apply this to my Zener diode simulations?

Breakdown voltage - The voltage which is greater than the barrier potential, beyond which the reverse current is not longer negligible and increases greatly.

I would appreciate if the accuracy of my understanding of the terms could be confirmed. Also, how do I put all this together to analyze and conclude my results of varying IS, BV and N?

Comment: The emission coefficient is a model parameter and there are actually several of them. But I think you are talking about the forward biased one in the Ebers-Moll model. In a small signal BJT, it's n=1 mostly. In diodes, it's often n=1.7 to n=3 (sometimes.) There is a thermal voltage (kT/q) that is modified by n to be (nkT/q), instead. It's tweaked to help fit the idealized model to observed behavior.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your comment. How does this affect the I-V characteristic graph of the diode?

Comment: I wasn't trying to explain everything. If I were, I'd write an answer. I just wanted to dash off a possibly helpful note. The thermal voltage concept either means something to you or it doesn't. If it does, you might understand why a model parameter that fusses with that value may be needed. If not, it's beyond my interest to answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

> These terms are not entirely clear to me, so analyzing the results of my simulations would be problematic.

Your understanding of the terms is on the right track, but let's clarify them further and then talk about how you might interpret the results of your simulations.

#### 1. Saturation Current (IS):

**What is it?**
The saturation current, (I_S), represents the reverse-biased current that flows due to minority carriers in the semiconductor. It's a tiny current, often in the nano or picoampere range, and is present even in the absence of external voltage because of thermal energy.

**In Zener Diodes:**
While (I_S) is more commonly associated with the Shockley diode equation for regular diodes in forward bias, in the context of a Zener diode, increasing (I_S) might mean a larger 'leakage' or 'minority carrier' current before breakdown.

#### 2. Emission Coefficient (N):

**What is it?**
The emission coefficient, (N), often termed the ideality factor, determines how closely the diode follows the ideal diode equation. A value of (N = 1) suggests ideal diode behavior, while values > 1 suggest some non-idealities due to recombination, generation, or tunneling processes.

**In Zener Diodes:**
For Zener diodes, the value of (N) typically affects the forward-biased behavior more than the reverse breakdown. A larger (N) can mean a softer knee in the forward I-V curve.

#### 3. Breakdown Voltage (BV):

**What is it?**
Breakdown voltage, (BV), is the reverse voltage at which the diode starts conducting a significant reverse current. For Zener diodes, this is the voltage at which the Zener effect (or avalanche breakdown for higher voltage Zeners) takes place.

**In Zener Diodes:**
The Zener voltage is the key specification for a Zener diode. It's the voltage at which you get a sharp rise in reverse current.

#### Interpreting Simulation Results:

1. **Varying IS:**

   - If you increase (I_S), expect to see a slight increase in reverse current before reaching the Zener breakdown. However, the primary Zener breakdown behavior might not change dramatically.
2. **Varying N:**

   - As you change (N), the forward-biased behavior of the Zener diode will be more affected than the reverse breakdown. A larger (N) might result in a softer forward knee in the I-V curve.
3. **Varying BV:**

   - Changing (BV) directly impacts the reverse breakdown voltage. A Zener diode with a higher (BV) will start conducting significant reverse current at a higher reverse voltage.

In conclusion, to analyze your simulation results:

- **Plot I-V Curves:** Look at both forward and reverse bias. Notice how the knee of the curve changes with (N) and how the reverse breakdown shifts with (BV).
- **Examine Breakdown Behavior:** Observe the exact voltage at which the diode goes into breakdown for different (BV) values.
- **Check Forward Bias:** Although Zener diodes are primarily used for their reverse bias properties, it's still instructive to look at the forward bias behavior, especially when you vary (N).

Remember, while the SPICE model captures a lot of the diode's behavior, real-world characteristics like temperature dependence, noise, and device-to-device variations might not be fully represented. Always cross-check with datasheets when designing real-world circuits.